# Максимальное пересечение отрезков на прямой

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дано множество отрезков с целыми концами на прямой. Найти максимальное количество отрезков, имеющих общую точку.

Вход: N, 2 массива.

Например:

```
Начало: 0 0 1
Конец : 1 2 2
Ответ : 3

Начало: 0 2 4
Конец : 1 3 5
Ответ : 1
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, советы для решения или идею какую-нибудь для эффективного решения.

Comment: Задача полностью аналогична https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1051531/%D0%A3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0. Это одна и то же задача, сформулированная косметически по-разному. Решается точно так же.

Answer (score 2):

1. Сортируем пары из координаты и типа по возрастанию координаты, при равенстве - сначала начало, потом конец.
2. Заводим переменную со значением 0.
3. Проходим по получившемуся массиву, для начала добавляем, а для конца вычитаем 1 из этой переменной.
4. Максимальное из значений этой переменной - это ответ.

Comment: а как сортировать пары ? по началу ?

Comment: Конец и начало - это две точки, а не одна.